# Need to pin a lightning component so it is always visible on the page

Tags: lightning, javascript, aura

Let's say i have a custom lightning component which have some kind of message embedded. When i add my custom lightning component to a record page and the user is viewing the record page where the custom component is embedded and he is scrolling through the page, i want the message component to be always visible regardless of page scrolling.

I looked at the highlights panel CSS by inspecting chrome but they are using header which in this case it is not a header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use position `fixed` and set the other attributes like `top`, `right` or `left`, like below:

```
<div class="slds-theme_default" style="position:fixed;top:7rem;right:2rem;">
    some help text
</div>
```

You can put this in component and check.

> Using fixed position will make the element position itself with
>   respect to window port so even while scrolling it will be in same position.